How to show a matrix DAD has distinct eigenvalues, where D is a diagonal matrix and A is a highly structured matrix
If

D is a positive diagonal matrix with well-separated diagonal entries (in particular, $(1 + k) |D_{i - 1, i - 1} < D_{i, i} < (1 - k) D_{i + 1, i + 1}$, where $k$ is a constant and the diagonal entries are ordered in increasing magnitude).

$A = (1 - c)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T + c\mathbf{I}$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ (for instance, $A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}2 \\
\frac{1}2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ would be an example, with $c = \frac{1}2$).


Can we show that $DAD$ must have well-separated eigenvalues as well?
I have tried unsuccessfully to show this intuitive statement for many hours, but to no avail. Any insight would be deeply appreciated.
